# help to convert python ctypes struct to 64bit

Tags: python, struct, 32bit-64bit, ctypes

I found this script attached to [a thread in the fontforge-users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=slrnictd6c.s1n.mozbugbox%40mozbugbox.somehost.org).  It does *exactly* what I want.  However, it seems only to work on 32bit systems, and I would really like to use it on my 64bit system.

I've done a little reading but I can't work out how I should modify this script (presumably the stuct?) to make it work under a 64bit architecture.  Can anyone help?

Cheers!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim:ts=8:sw=4:expandtab:encoding=utf-8
# Export named font from PDF file using fontforge and ctypes

import sys
from ctypes import *

STRING = c_char_p
real = c_longdouble

# We need the `map` attribute of SplineFont, so declear an incomplete struct.
# see: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wqy/files/misc/
# file: fontforge-bindctypes-0.1.tar.bz2
class splinefont(Structure):
    pass
SplineFont = splinefont
splinefont._fields_ = [
    ('fontname', STRING),
    ('fullname', STRING),
    ('familyname', STRING),
    ('weight', STRING),
    ('copyright', STRING),
    ('filename', STRING),
    ('defbasefilename', STRING),
    ('version', STRING),
    ('italicangle', real),
    ('upos', real),
    ('uwidth', real),
    ('ascent', c_int),
    ('descent', c_int),
    ('uniqueid', c_int),
    ('glyphcnt', c_int),
    ('glyphmax', c_int),
    ('glyphs', POINTER(c_void_p)),
    ('changed', c_uint, 1),
    ('changed_since_autosave', c_uint, 1),
    ('changed_since_xuidchanged', c_uint, 1),
    ('display_antialias', c_uint, 1),
    ('display_bbsized', c_uint, 1),
    ('dotlesswarn', c_uint, 1),
    ('onlybitmaps', c_uint, 1),
    ('serifcheck', c_uint, 1),
    ('issans', c_uint, 1),
    ('isserif', c_uint, 1),
    ('hasvmetrics', c_uint, 1),
    ('loading_cid_map', c_uint, 1),
    ('dupnamewarn', c_uint, 1),
    ('encodingchanged', c_uint, 1),
    ('multilayer', c_uint, 1),
    ('strokedfont', c_uint, 1),
    ('new', c_uint, 1),
    ('compacted', c_uint, 1),
    ('backedup', c_uint, 2),
    ('use_typo_metrics', c_uint, 1),
    ('weight_width_slope_only', c_uint, 1),
    ('save_to_dir', c_uint, 1),
    ('head_optimized_for_cleartype', c_uint, 1),
    ('ticked', c_uint, 1),
    ('internal_temp', c_uint, 1),
    ('complained_about_spiros', c_uint, 1),
    ('use_xuid', c_uint, 1),
    ('use_uniqueid', c_uint, 1),
    ('fv', c_void_p),
    ('metrics', c_void_p),
    ('uni_interp', c_int),
    ('for_new_glyphs', c_void_p),
    ('map', c_void_p),
    # ...
]

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print "Usage: %s doc.pdf fontname" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(2)
    pdfname = sys.argv[1]
    fontname = sys.argv[2]
    fontfile = fontname + '.ttf'

    # ctypes functions
    libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
    libc.fopen.restype = c_void_p
    libc.fopen.argtype = [c_char_p, c_char_p]

    lib_ff = CDLL('libfontforge.so.1')

    # SplineFont *_SFReadPdfFont(FILE *pdf,char *filename,
    #     char *select_this_font, enum openflags openflags)
    lib_ff._SFReadPdfFont.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_int]
    lib_ff._SFReadPdfFont.restype = POINTER(SplineFont)

    # int GenerateScript(SplineFont *sf, char *filename, char *bitmaptype,
    #     int fmflags, int res, char *subfontdefinition, struct sflist *sfs,
    #     EncMap *map, NameList *rename_to,int layer)
    lib_ff.GenerateScript.argytpes = [POINTER(SplineFont), c_char_p, c_char_p,
            c_int, c_int, c_char_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_int]
    lib_ff.GenerateScript.restype = c_int

    # need to somehow initialize libfontforge or it will segfault somewhere.
    lib_ff.doinitFontForgeMain()
    fobj = libc.fopen(pdfname, "rb")
    if not fobj:
        print "%s not found" % pdfname
        sys.exit(1)

    font = lib_ff._SFReadPdfFont(fobj, pdfname, fontname, 0)
    ret = 0
    if bool(font):
        ret = lib_ff.GenerateScript(font, fontfile, None, -1, -1, None, None,
                font.contents.map, None, 1)
    if ret:
        print 'Font export to "%s".' % fontfile
    else:
        print "** Error ** Failed to export font!!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why did someone code this in Python?  It's one of the very few things I would have done in C.

Comment: @Sven Marnach - I can see your point.  From my own perspective, I'm looking for a way to call this from within a more complicated python script, so this approach, if I can get it to work, appeals to me.  If I was able to rewrite this in C I would be open to that, but I suppose I would still have to deal with the same architecture issue?

Comment: I can't see a reason for a 64-bit problem, neither in the Python code above nor in recoding it in C.  But the C version of this script would be really short.  You could call it from Python as a subprocess or via ctypes.

Comment: you could just run the 32 bit version of Python

Comment: @David Heffernan: yeah, that's actually what I am doing at the moment, but it's awkward and thoroughly unsatisfying... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is whether FONTFORGE_CONFIG_USE_LONGDOUBLE is defined or not in /usr/include/fontforge/config.h. If it is defined, then the code's definition is correct. On my amd64 linux installation, neither FONTFORGE_CONFIG_USE_LONGDOUBLE nor  FONTFORGE_CONFIG_USE_DOUBLE are defined, so I needed to change

```
real = c_float
```

With that change, it works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I can't replicate your results!  On my installation (64bit Ubuntu 10.10), too, neither `FONTFORGE_CONFIG_USE_LONGDOUBLE` nor `FONTFORGE_CONFIG_USE_DOUBLE` are defined in `/usr/include/fontforge/config.h`, but changing the definition of `real` to `c_float` still results in a segfault.  Could it be something else (too)?

Comment: For further analysis, you'll have to provide a specific PDF file and a specific invocation. I can't think of anything else that may be causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  If you're willing to look at it, I've posted my test pdf here (http://simonwiles.net/test_fore.pdf) - it's just the first multi-lingual thing I had at hand, for testing.  It only contains two fonts (PMingLiu and Gentium), and the script is capable of extracting them on 32bit systems with the invocations `python ff_font_extract.py test_fore.pdf BAAAAA+Gentium` and `python ff_font_extract.py test_fore.pdf CAAAAA+PMingLiU`.  May I ask what 64bit Linux distro you had it working on?  (ps. - I greatly appreciate your helpfulness!)

Comment: Both fonts export fine with the change. I'm using Debian testing, libfontforge 0.0.20100501-2. I agree with the posters who said that this is better written in C.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I can confirm this with Debian testing and this version of the libfontforge library.  I'll try to track the difference down, but you've sorted it out.  Thanks :)